# How can I start app in \\SERVER and it initialized in C:\Windows\Temp with WineHQ?

Tags: xubuntu, wine, winetricks

My client machine runs Xubuntu 20.04 and wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1).

I have a application delphi who needs to start on server (\SERVER\app\old_app.exe), but it needs to run/stores on C:\Windows\Temp. However, this application uses BDE (another application) installed in the client machine to access Data Base (this, shared on \SERVER\data-base\db.fdb). It's two old applications and I'm trying run it from Wine. I succeed to run BDE and it access data base.

"Server" runs Windows 7 x64 and other client machines run XP, 7 and 10 Windows version. Enterprise who make old_app.exe don't wanna make an able app client to run especifically in client side.

[image]

How can I run old_app.exe with this espacifications with WineHQ?

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon.

I find the solution. Here:

```
wine start "D:\\SRV_Shop\\programa\\shop.exe" -wo "c:\\windows\\temp"
```

- D: is an mounted windows shared folder in Wine; and
- -wo is a windows command prompt to start shop.exe in  c:\windows\temp.

HOWEVER, my friends... it can't start normally. shop.exe can't found database alias although that BDE application it'a started. It's BDE the application responsible for provide connection with BDE.

Someone can help?